# Type Chinese into VcXsrv(or other X Server) using Windows-pinyin IME

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver, xming

I want to run `IDEA` in WSL(windows subsystem for linux) so I followed [wsl-tutorial.](https://github.com/QMonkey/wsl-tutorial) But I don't want `xfce4` desktop because costs performance, so I just install needed GUI packages and run `IDEA` succussfully. But unfortunately I can't type Chinese in it using Windows-pinyin IME, so I have to install `xfce4` and `fcitx-pinyin` then it works.

Is it possible to type Chinese into VcXsrv(or other X Server) using Windows-pinyin IME? VcXsrv support `clipboard` so I think it's possible to do that.

[image]